# why does filter + abs functions not give correct value

Tags: python-3.x, filter, absolute-value

```
numbers = list(range(-10,10))
print(numbers)
newnum = filter(abs,numbers)
print(list(newnum))
print(abs(-10))
```

it gives the output as below

```
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10
```

I thought it should have given as below

```
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter method filters the given sequence with the help of a function that tests each element in the sequence to be true or not. 
abs(x) returns the absolute value of a number.
**What is happening?**

- Each value from the numbers list is passed to abs function which is added to newnum list only if abs function returns true.
- Since abs returns a positive number, filter takes it as true and adds that number to newnum.
- *Except, in the case when that number is 0. abs returns 0 which is false and thus is not added to the newnum list.*

**filter returns the elements from numbers list which results in true when passed to abs function, not the returned value from the abs function.**